# starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown

Tags: docker

When I am login docker kubernetes dashboard using this command:

```
docker exec -it ecd3ff5051df /bin/bash
```

Throw this error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown
```

I am searching the internet and tell me the alpline default using sh, then I am trying to login like this:

```
docker exec -it ecd3ff5051df /bin/sh
```

throw this error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown
```

where is the problem? Thank you.this is my docker info:

```
[root@log001 ~]# docker inspect 47c0c3b512cb
[
    {
        "Id": "47c0c3b512cbc15e7db1753d1d255346532e5f94b5b013da70074cffd6ea70ff",
        "Created": "2019-09-22T10:40:59.197328264Z",
        "Path": "/dashboard",
        "Args": [
            "--insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0",
            "--bind-address=0.0.0.0",
            "--auto-generate-certificates"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 22632,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2019-09-22T10:40:59.680933289Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:f9aed6605b814b69e92dece6a50ed1e4e730144eb1cc971389dde9cb3820d124",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/ecd3ff5051df0ed2a8b8bc5e2145dfcbf630d834cdb35572230d1a5cb4d60852/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/ecd3ff5051df0ed2a8b8bc5e2145dfcbf630d834cdb35572230d1a5cb4d60852/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/opt/k8s/k8s/kubelet/pods/9b8ba20d-f379-4b83-8d85-5901f26308c7/etc-hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/47c0c3b512cbc15e7db1753d1d255346532e5f94b5b013da70074cffd6ea70ff/47c0c3b512cbc15e7db1753d1d255346532e5f94b5b013da70074cffd6ea70ff-json.log",
        "Name": "/k8s_kubernetes-dashboard_kubernetes-dashboard-74d7cc788-mk9c7_kube-system_9b8ba20d-f379-4b83-8d85-5901f26308c7_2",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/opt/k8s/k8s/kubelet/pods/9b8ba20d-f379-4b83-8d85-5901f26308c7/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/kubernetes-dashboard-certs:/certs:ro",
                "/opt/k8s/k8s/kubelet/pods/9b8ba20d-f379-4b83-8d85-5901f26308c7/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/tmp-volume:/tmp",
                "/opt/k8s/k8s/kubelet/pods/9b8ba20d-f379-4b83-8d85-5901f26308c7/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/kubernetes-dashboard-token-pmxpf:/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount:ro",
                "/opt/k8s/k8s/kubelet/pods/9b8ba20d-f379-4b83-8d85-5901f26308c7/etc-hosts:/etc/hosts",
                "/opt/k8s/k8s/kubelet/pods/9b8ba20d-f379-4b83-8d85-5901f26308c7/containers/kubernetes-dashboard/50339ad7:/dev/termination-log"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "container:ecd3ff5051df0ed2a8b8bc5e2145dfcbf630d834cdb35572230d1a5cb4d60852",
            "PortBindings": null,
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "container:ecd3ff5051df0ed2a8b8bc5e2145dfcbf630d834cdb35572230d1a5cb4d60852",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": -998,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 51,
            "Memory": 314572800,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "/kubepods/burstable/pod9b8ba20d-f379-4b83-8d85-5901f26308c7",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 100000,
            "CpuQuota": 10000,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 314572800,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9f0d685998ea4b8fce36e79ddb90f33b115d4d12468845a08472d350f29d8c52-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/32329fe5a56eea9514b732989f53864544c8bf24c97fb53ace9cbc82784e67d2/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9f0d685998ea4b8fce36e79ddb90f33b115d4d12468845a08472d350f29d8c52/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9f0d685998ea4b8fce36e79ddb90f33b115d4d12468845a08472d350f29d8c52/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9f0d685998ea4b8fce36e79ddb90f33b115d4d12468845a08472d350f29d8c52/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/opt/k8s/k8s/kubelet/pods/9b8ba20d-f379-4b83-8d85-5901f26308c7/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/tmp-volume",
                "Destination": "/tmp",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/opt/k8s/k8s/kubelet/pods/9b8ba20d-f379-4b83-8d85-5901f26308c7/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/kubernetes-dashboard-token-pmxpf",
                "Destination": "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount",
                "Mode": "ro",
                "RW": false,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/opt/k8s/k8s/kubelet/pods/9b8ba20d-f379-4b83-8d85-5901f26308c7/etc-hosts",
                "Destination": "/etc/hosts",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/opt/k8s/k8s/kubelet/pods/9b8ba20d-f379-4b83-8d85-5901f26308c7/containers/kubernetes-dashboard/50339ad7",
                "Destination": "/dev/termination-log",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/opt/k8s/k8s/kubelet/pods/9b8ba20d-f379-4b83-8d85-5901f26308c7/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/kubernetes-dashboard-certs",
                "Destination": "/certs",
                "Mode": "ro",
                "RW": false,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "kubernetes-dashboard-74d7cc788-mk9c7",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "0",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "8443/tcp": {},
                "9090/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.254.0.1:443",
                "KUBE_DNS_SERVICE_PORT_DNS_TCP=53",
                "KUBE_DNS_PORT_53_UDP_PORT=53",
                "KUBERNETES_DASHBOARD_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp",
                "KUBE_DNS_SERVICE_PORT_DNS=53",
                "KUBE_DNS_SERVICE_PORT_METRICS=9153",
                "KUBE_DNS_PORT_53_UDP=udp://10.254.0.2:53",
                "KUBE_DNS_PORT_53_UDP_ADDR=10.254.0.2",
                "KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443",
                "KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443",
                "KUBERNETES_DASHBOARD_SERVICE_PORT=443",
                "KUBERNETES_DASHBOARD_PORT=tcp://10.254.75.193:443",
                "KUBERNETES_DASHBOARD_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.254.75.193:443",
                "KUBE_DNS_SERVICE_HOST=10.254.0.2",
                "KUBE_DNS_PORT_53_TCP_PORT=53",
                "KUBE_DNS_PORT_9153_TCP=tcp://10.254.0.2:9153",
                "KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.254.0.1:443",
                "KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.254.0.1",
                "KUBERNETES_DASHBOARD_SERVICE_HOST=10.254.75.193",
                "KUBE_DNS_PORT_9153_TCP_ADDR=10.254.0.2",
                "KUBERNETES_DASHBOARD_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.254.75.193",
                "KUBE_DNS_SERVICE_PORT=53",
                "KUBE_DNS_PORT_9153_TCP_PORT=9153",
                "KUBE_DNS_PORT_53_UDP_PROTO=udp",
                "KUBE_DNS_PORT_53_TCP_PROTO=tcp",
                "KUBE_DNS_PORT_53_TCP=tcp://10.254.0.2:53",
                "KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443",
                "KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp",
                "KUBE_DNS_PORT=udp://10.254.0.2:53",
                "KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.254.0.1",
                "KUBE_DNS_PORT_9153_TCP_PROTO=tcp",
                "KUBERNETES_DASHBOARD_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443",
                "KUBE_DNS_PORT_53_TCP_ADDR=10.254.0.2",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "--auto-generate-certificates"
            ],
            "Healthcheck": {
                "Test": [
                    "NONE"
                ]
            },
            "Image": "sha256:f9aed6605b814b69e92dece6a50ed1e4e730144eb1cc971389dde9cb3820d124",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/dashboard",
                "--insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0",
                "--bind-address=0.0.0.0"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "annotation.io.kubernetes.container.hash": "b11195e",
                "annotation.io.kubernetes.container.ports": "[{\"containerPort\":8443,\"protocol\":\"TCP\"}]",
                "annotation.io.kubernetes.container.restartCount": "2",
                "annotation.io.kubernetes.container.terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
                "annotation.io.kubernetes.container.terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
                "annotation.io.kubernetes.pod.terminationGracePeriod": "30",
                "io.kubernetes.container.logpath": "/var/log/pods/kube-system_kubernetes-dashboard-74d7cc788-mk9c7_9b8ba20d-f379-4b83-8d85-5901f26308c7/kubernetes-dashboard/2.log",
                "io.kubernetes.container.name": "kubernetes-dashboard",
                "io.kubernetes.docker.type": "container",
                "io.kubernetes.pod.name": "kubernetes-dashboard-74d7cc788-mk9c7",
                "io.kubernetes.pod.namespace": "kube-system",
                "io.kubernetes.pod.uid": "9b8ba20d-f379-4b83-8d85-5901f26308c7",
                "io.kubernetes.sandbox.id": "ecd3ff5051df0ed2a8b8bc5e2145dfcbf630d834cdb35572230d1a5cb4d60852",
                "maintainer": "Piotr Bryk <bryk@google.com>"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {}
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t `docker exec` or `kubectl exec` into this container at all, because it doesn’t have any interactive tools you could run.

There’s no requirement that a Docker image contain a shell or any other debugging tools, and particularly in the case of Go-based binaries it’s not that uncommon to have an extremely minimal image that *only* contains the application and absolutely nothing else.

If you look at the [dashboard Dockerfile](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/aio/Dockerfile) you’ll see that it’s structured as

```
FROM scratch
ADD . /
```

There’s absolutely nothing at all in the `scratch` base image — no shell, no libraries, nothing.  So the only things in the official dashboard image are the things that come out of the Kubernetes source tree; there isn’t a `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` (or even a `/bin` directory).